# when training a model with tensorflow-gpu and GPU 4090 on WSL, abnormal loss got

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, wsl-2

I recently bought a new 4090 for deep learning. After installed nvidia driver, I started to run the programme on WSL2 for training the model I have successfually trained without gpu.
However, with GPU acceleration, the loss are abnormal:

```
363/363 [==============================] - 191s 19ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0964 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 2/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0850 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 3/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0865 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 4/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0890 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 5/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0931 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 6/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0889 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 7/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0827 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 8/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0888 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 9/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0880 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
Epoch 10/10
363/363 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.0845 - val_loss: nan - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0983
```

And I found erorrs and warnings as following:

`E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:927] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node`

`W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:63] Running ptxas --version returned 256`
`Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.`
`Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.`

reinstalled nvidia driver
installed cuda tools

Comment: It may be that the loss blows up...havent seen that

Comment: Please share the minimal reproducible code to replicate the error. Please ensure that you have installed all the required libraries for GPU setup as per this [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and set the path accordingly by following these [steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements). Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.